# Gradle JAVA_HOME path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a problem running Gradle project in eclipse Neon.2.
I find out that there is a problem with JDK path.
Somehow my gradle in elipse always use some strange JRE as a Java Home, when it should use a path to a JDK. I double checked my settings in eclipse and system variables, but still i cant find the solution.

I searched for answers and find out that people suggested changing Gradle settings in elipse.
I did all the settings but it still doesnt work.

[All the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6dUl.png)

Btw, if I manualy set the Java Home while creating Gradle project it all works fine. But it has to work on other computers so I cant really use that solution.

[That works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoHwt.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Preference of Eclipse (main menu: Window -> Preferences), select

Gradle -> Arguments -> Java Home, select "Workspace JRE".

Then select one of your jdk in your workspace.

Comment: There's no "Argument" section under Gradle for me

Comment: It should be, Can you post some screen shot here with version your using and so.

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen 3a. Screenshot of Eclipse: https://imgur.com/cRfF2D0
Any way, I fixed it by specifying the java path in `C:\Users\YourUserName\.gradle\gradle.properties` file

Comment: There is no such argument  in 4.7.2 oxygen version of eclispe. @zhuhang.jasper. How did you set the value in gradle.properties?

Comment: @rinilnath have you tried the above answer by mujibur-rahman ?

Comment: @zhuhang.jasper, Yes, i edited gradle.properties in my local project folder to hold the value of JDK home from my system. org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/JDK1.8.0.45

Answer (score 4):

```
Create/update gradle.properties in GRADLE_USER_HOME ( C:\users\<user>/.gradle or linux ~/.gradle) with 

org.gradle.java.home=<path to jdk>
```